# Passing managed event handler to unmanaged code in Linux

Tags: c#, c++

I've been writing a .Net Core C# wrapper for an existing C++ library that will run under Linux. The library has the following:

```
int newrelic_record_metric(const char *name, double value);

void newrelic_register_message_handler(void*(*handler)(void*));

void *newrelic_message_handler(void *raw_message);
```

The first method is easy enough to wrap:

```
internal static class AgentSdkWrapper {
    [DllImport("newrelic-transaction")]
    public static extern unsafe int newrelic_record_metric(StringBuilder name, double value);
```

I'm struggling with the signature of the second version, I don't know how I would translate that to C#. I understand I'm dealing with void pointers, but I'm unsure what to do with them.

Also, according to the library docs, I need to register the third method as a callback to the second method:

> You must register the required callback that will send data to New Relic when transactions are  completed. You will need to register the default newrelic_message_handler callback that has already been defined:
>
> newrelic_register_message_handler(newrelic_message_handler);

I presume I need to assign `newrelic_message_handler` to a C# delegate and pass that into `newrelic_register_message_handler`, but I'm unclear how I get there.

Comment: Obviously `void *` parameter and return value won't works well in C#... How P/Invoke would be able to do appropriate conversion? As far as I know P/Invoke would more or less only support callback similar to those used by the Win32 API. If you want custom stuff, then maybe you should have a mixed/mode C++/CLI DLL doing the translation between native and managed code. In any case, you want to avoid to bring your existing mess in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the doc correctly you just need to pass a pointer to `newrelic_message_handler` to the second function.

It means that for all intents and purposes your 2nd function will look like this:

```
[DllImport(...)]
static extern void newrelic_register_message_handler(IntPtr handler);
```

Because actually you are just passing a pointer and don't really care about types.

To get a pointer to `newrelic_message_handler` (assuming that this is a dll exported function) you need to use `GetProcAdress`

```
[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
```

And your final code will be:

```
var module = LoadLibrary("newrelic-transaction");
var proc = GetProcAddress(module, "newrelic_message_handler");
newrelic_register_message_handler(proc);
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? We can't learn anything from simply casting a downvote...

Comment: I omitted a very important detail - I am running on Linux, so `kernel32` is unavailable to me.

Comment: With a little fiddling to make this compatible on Linux, I got this working based on your code. Cheers!